# How to connect private network through android device programmatically

Tags: android

How do we make handheld devices secure to login to a domain (mobile device management)? For example: if you have a laptop or if you are working from home using a desktop, you do a VPN and connect to your company’s domain. Once you connect, only then you can access your work email, share point sites, timesheets, etc. So instead of laptops and desktops, how do we create/develop an app on mobile devices which can ensure 100% security to the environment which we are connecting to.i dont have any idea regaring this.Anybody know, just help me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is essentially establishing a VPN tunnel. The issue with that is that Android does not support the Cisco protocol/extensions out-of-the-box. Cisco have released versions of [AnyConnect](https://market.android.com/developer?pub=Cisco+Systems,+Inc.) for phone brands (different kernels, with/without tun.ko, etc.) but that means your users would have to manually connect to the VPN first. You *really* do not want to implement your own VPN. In fact, you don't want to implement *any* cryptography whatsoever, since you are guaranteed to get it wrong.

Unfortunately, there's little automation that could be done without root access or support from Cisco (e.g., hooks to start connecting via an external intent). Given root access, you could just run the command-line `openvpn` tool with a pre-configured config and establish a VPN tunnel to your facilities. This is not an entirely brilliant idea but at least you're not dealing with crypto directly (just kernel versions, tun/tap.ko modules, etc.). The upside of OpenVPN is the granularity of control. The downside of OpenVPN is the granularity of control, i.e. setting up CAs, Server/Client certificate pairs, etc (which you'll need if you're at all serious about doing this on a large scale).

Of course, the *easiest* solution, if starting completely from scratch, would be to use Android's built-in VPN support. However, that's limited to a subset of L2TP/IPSec, which are not trivial to set up or that widely deployed.

Once the tunnel is established, the rest is just access to the local network.